# Ошибка Out of memory (allocated 15466496) (tried to allocate > 262144 bytes)

Tags: php

вопрос в чем у меня по тарифу

```
 Для акселераторов PHP, Мб  На процесс, Мб
          256                    1024
```

в конвектере я получаю что 15466496 байт это  15 м.б. объясните может я чего то не понимаю поскольку хостер на чистом глазу рассказывает что мне надо изменить тариф и увеличить объем оперативки? Вопрос для разговора с хостером  в каких измерениях считается эта ошибка?

Comment: Вам английским по белому написано `262144 bytes`. А вот как именно измеряет память хостер - уже вопрос. Что-то мне подсказывает, что "на процесс" - имеется в виду на процесс apache с php и может еще чем-то. Иными словами -- пора менять хостера

Comment: если есть доступ к `php.ini` увеличьте значение `momory_limit`, ошибка оттуда идёт. Или попросите техсупорт это сделать

Comment: @Den С нашей стороны решением может быть лишь переход на другой тариф, на котором доступно больше памяти.  Вот ответ хостера.

Comment: @Sergalas [тут](http://techpp.com/2009/07/10/how-to-fix-php-fatal-error-out-of-memory/) прикольные обходы для этой проблеммы нащёл. Можно даже через `.htaccess` настроить параметры памяти в обход `php.ini`.

Comment: @Den а можно как то очистить память после каждой итерации цикла.

Comment: @Sergalas [тутава](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) и  [тутава](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php). Но это геморно.. доступ к терманалу есть?